# Is there any way to create custom drawable folders based on themes?

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I have one theme -> theme1

it has to pick the drawable from the drawable-theme1 folder.

is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to use a theme name as drawable folder `qualifier`

The available qualifiers are in the table 2 at this link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

If you can't find a valid alternative using the provided ones maybe you should think if a "drawable-theme" folder is the right approach to solve your problem